# Parsing a regex-like string

Tags: python, regex, string, sed, grep

I'm trying to parse a Regex-like string, with format like the following:

- The only characters that need to be escaped are: `[`, `\`, and `-`;
- A valid string can be a sequence of:

  - "regular characters", e.g. `a`, `b`
  - "escaped special characters", e.g. `\\`, `\[`
  - Sequences containing above two, wrapped by a pair of brackets, e.g. `[abc]`, `[a\]]`

For example, `abc[def]g`, `abc\-\[[def\]]gh\\` are both valid strings.

Is there some way that I can get the character / character class (in the third case above) at each index? Using pure `regex`/`sed` or some Python library works for me.

Comment: can get the character / character class (in the third case above) at each index <-- what does that mean?

Comment: I'm also confused by your question. It would seem to method what you have there is already valid regex, so you could just use it as a regex pattern and be done with it, but surely it can't be that easy, so I'm really not sure what you're really asking.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion -- what I meant is essentially I can get the individual regular characters and character groups, e.g. `abc[def]g` becomes `[a,b,c, [d,e,f], g]`. It's trickier than regular regex because the only characters that need escaping are `[`, `\`, `-`. Therefore, if I have a string like `\`, it wouldn't be valid regex but a valid string in this grammar. With more thoughts, I think I'll just gonna parse it char-by-char in Python.

Comment: Essentially, if you support escaping, it should be allowed for all characters. When you parse, parse for _escape + any character_ as well.

Comment: @sln Yep that's what I'm planning to do -- so if I see an unescaped `\`, I would simply parse the next char as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, you can't parse it character by character, but have to parse it
construct by construct.

Knowing the group that matched tells you what the construct is.
When the *class* construct matches, you have to parse it's contents
separate from the main regex.

You'd check this all in (pseudo-code)

*while( regex find )

{

if group 1 matched // the character escaped

else

if group 2 matched // a non-class start or non-escaped char

   // Check if it should be escaped, or is a metachar

else

if group 3 matched // class contents

    // parse the class contents here

else

if group 4 matched // error

}*

For example purposes ..

`(?s)(?:\\(.)|([^\[])|\[((?:\\.|[^\]])*)\]|(.))`

Expanded

```
 (?s)                # Dot all modifier
 (?:
      \\                  # Escape anything
      ( . )               # (1)
   |                    # or,
      ( [^\[] )           # (2), Anything that does not start a char class
   |                    # or,
      \[                  # Start of char class
      (                   # (3 start)
           (?:                 # ----------
                \\ .                # Escape anything
             |                    # or,
                [^\]]               # Anthing that does not end a char class
           )*                  # ----------
      )                   # (3 end)
      \]                  # End of char class
   |                    # or,
      ( . )               # (4), Error, probably an unbalanced '['     
 )
```